# type widening on generic parameter losing type safety

Tags: typescript

I have created [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKKDGAeAonUGYAOwBMBnOXAG2AFsSYA+OAXjgG8AoOOMKCGAD8ALjjkYUAJbEA5gG4ecWcBhEo5UXABKwTNFLYJ0uQBo4ACmC0GxGGNwBKNi2MzZTRQF8uXUJFg4TGoAQ3JKABUAC3c8AhAiMkoaekZzNHjEinQsPCYWbl59YmMAV0wYaAslXjBSgCNqKUw4YhCGMTczGr5pADcQonEsKQAzZsGpCGIxNFMlZw4fHz9waHgkFDgASTtgKBCK6F2JEOJMYDjCEmyU2xh0zJvKDD08lnZo2Nx0z19-dYIZCoADiqnU2zoYBsjEm0yuCWeVBhdke1ySOTeuHybE4SgA2gAFOAyOAAa2AiAgo3Q+IA5Co1PtyHSALqs2b0xnqFmsomsp4YixWFH2KjmAB0UpCUFk5DEpWIZOIEAA7sR8aznKwWIrlWriM4hJYBtRSsBOpJ3NqWLt1IdKlATjAzhc8L84GJiMA+vtvP81oFNqg7fsHdAIsCEVlkqK0YiMa8cNiPkphabzZaTLIbTs9gcjk6Si7zpcfugmM4AGRKMFMp1Q0Vw4juiuKAMBeCjRUVKbEIJQYCDYBfOTRpF3RhMCxtDriK1yRZKQcwUpQfvd84wPvYDLo7JJ94WcgjcaYZuzJe8IrTCRwQfkUrUeDsTe96YWDMW+fZxxiUeyK2aAFD0vC0BsMRyLi3qqnAAFAdOs7AOYJ56GMEzbtMjiKNe14rmu-YwJBCg9CsuH4eu97AI+z5wGEeb2oWkYoAhOFwMsvjFHeAAyMhkrimCDsO8EABIRAAstxvFKpOdjTnSTRKnSjgWIUvSCGIdIhHS8y8NyzJiGpvD1IgXzypY1ipHYuaWfcEpRIOoy6deJnRIMYgilZMA2aKErbjAtBKF4zmqlEEAAMIytRADqUSDGZ2zmQAbClEpwAA9Ol4hhU+pCtBA8D1KgUT7MAXBeNhviZXBIlSJQdVwKFiCYi03rANklRwEVdHKCQ+zNECWwyrIpT3Fw1XbHApAQOIEAMNlJBnFIshnPV-bcRA56OpC0Jec2CAzSEpB5UR1GoPwgiUNMnWnXBxFcNJZISq5cUwBYdL1PUymKI9z2mTE5DvZgmDKb4QA) with this code

```js
export type Spec<E extends Element> = {
  prop?: string;
  getters?: Record<string, (element: E) => string>;
}

export class Thing<E extends Element, S extends Spec<E>> {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    private specification: S,
  ) {}
}

export type InteractorInstance<E extends Element, S extends Spec<E>> = Thing<E, S>;

export type GetterImplementation<E extends Element, S extends Spec<E>> = {
  [P in keyof S['getters']]: S['getters'][P] extends ((element: E, ...args: unknown[]) => unknown) ? (value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, S> : never;
}

export type InteractorType<E extends Element, S extends Spec<E>> =
  ((value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, S>) &
  GetterImplementation<E, S>;


export function createThing<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return function<S extends Spec<E>>(specification: S) {
    const result = function(value: string): Thing<E, S> {
      let thing = new Thing<E, S>(name, specification);
      return thing;
    }

    return result as InteractorType<E, S>;
  }
}

const Link = createThing<HTMLLinkElement>('link')({
  prop: 'a',
  getters: {
    byThis: (element) => element.href,
    byThat: (element) => element.title
  },
  whoCaresWhatThisIs: 666. // should not be here
});

// THis is why Spec needs to be a generic type argument
// I do some shenanigans in LocatorImplementation to add these props onto the Thing
Link.byThat('bb');
Link.byThis('cc')
```

Can I make the `Spec` only have the keys of `Spec`, i.e. anything other than `prop` or `getters` is invalid?

I need Spec to be a type argument because it is used in a conditional type in `SpecImplementation`

Comment: What do you mean by "is not strongly typed"?

Comment: Relevant: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-match-the-exact-object-shape/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out earlier, `S extends Spec` allows extra properties - exactly what you want to avoid!

But let's see why you need to extend Spec exactly... Looks like you need you be able to provide a custom map of getters, while in `Spec` it's defined as `Record<string, Function>`. Ok - so isn't it the clue then? Let's make Spec itself generic, parameterized by the keys in this record:

```
export type Spec<E extends Element, G extends string> = {
  prop?: string;
  getters?: Record<G, (element: E) => string>;
}
```

Then we update all derived types correspondingly. Note that `GetterImplementation` mapped type becomes simpler now, as it works directly with the new generic parameter:

```
export type GetterImplementation<E extends Element, G extends string> = {
  [P in G]: (value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, G>;
}
```

(in fact I might have misunderstood the intention with this mapped type... if you do want smart handling of getters, it should be made a part of `Spec` - currently `Spec` doesn't allow to have a getter with extra arguments).

And finally, the function itself is gonna be generic with the new `G extends string` generic parameter instead of `Spec`:

```
export function createThing<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return function<G extends string>(specification: Spec<E, G>) {
    const result = function(value: string): Thing<E, G> {
      let thing = new Thing<E, G>(name, specification);
      return thing;
    }

    return result as InteractorType<E, G>;
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKKDGAeAonUGYAOwBMBnOXAG2AFsSYAaOAcQJCLMvJigEtiAcwB8cALxwA3gCg4cMFAhgA-AC44vAcIDccuEOAwiUcurgAlYJmilsrFgApgtBsRgbcASglitg0T0AXxkZUEhYOExqAENySgAVAAsAvA4uCipXRhZ2QhJM-2ExWXkbYi0AV0wYaEd9eTBKgCNqfkw4YhiGDSKhJgaFAQA3GKJNLH4AM3ax-ghiDQxrPFyRAfkfKRCQsPBoeCQUOABJd2AoGJroM94Y4kxgNPzuLPoctnSCnj4AsUlkqlcGs9HsIodkKhWEYTCc6GBsu45gtnpxvm83MxPi9Cr9ihJpPoANoABTggjYAF0NI5RtRKsBenihD5xGIziYrrUoLcYPdHqs2CJgqFwgcEJDTudLtcoAlIaiMpQaO93Lkvq8%20v99I5aTF6YzNMzWezpVybhU%20Q8nsChT4AGT6aHGC5whGqvkwebEQWsYWhMHiqaVB5ehZRKDAMbAQHCRXolWYkSOLo9I3aFmE%20SRmCVKDEODB0Pe%20wa3EZ5PkSYzTDIxboLC%20kRbQblXhwSPkSrUeCSIs1b16g1MjNeDSxoRNrPyGe0Q4pYQE4jAADucAnTZT3WALCr1mmszDxC8ehnM5zeYLMAXQlPM92Z4v%20Y7wC7PbgcSlnNl8pQTbvOyhG28AAIIEpgkbRhuAASCQALIADIIYIADWiaMMmADkbTEChmEnkBCztshuHgZBRAwfBSGoeh7hYTheFeI4pRDMoGiYTEmEbAYMIXOQGgsfIzSIIC-FwM4iIwCaBCSQAdEkkZTNxQkiUkYw0i4HrSZpmKyV6MC0PoQTcQA9CZcArkkEAAMIxJ2ADqakwKJJxiQAbB5slwGZmhWd2pCdBA8DNKgSQXMAMhBARMg%20Qk0H8JQCUWUkiANtYnTAMAmS1HAIUfjxy4CB0RyoHZQiVJiMXmSccCkBAmgQAwvkkPc-BCPciUFghEC1tybqSXWCD1TEpABder6oIoyiUAsOXjeuN4yCRKGycJyRjI4mHNM0%20F6Mtq2qQlm2YJg%20FAA)

Answer (score 1):

If Spec needs to be strongly typed, then why S extends Spec? I tried the following and the returned type didn't allow anything apart from props and getters,

```ts
export function createThing<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return function(specification: Spec<E>) {
    const result = function(value: string): Thing<E, Spec<E>> {
      let thing = new Thing<E, Spec<E>>(name, specification);
      return thing;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Checkout my forked playground here: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKKDGAeAonUGYAOwBMBnOXAG2AFsSYA+OAXjgG8AoOOMKCGAD8ALjjkYUAJbEA5gG4ecWcBhEo5UXABKwTNFLYJ0uQBo4ACmC0GxGGNwBKNi2MzZTRQF8uXUJFg4TGoAQ3JKABUAC3c8AhAiMkoaekZzNHjEinQsPCYWbl59YmMAV0wYaAslXjBSgCNqKUw4YhCGMTczGr5pADcQonEsKQAzZsGpCGIxNFMlZw4fHz9waHhR0uIKqeIgqGBB4GjY-EISbJTbZgs2jvFJd0WlA5hSqD3N7Zhdi3IR8aYSbTWa5XBMZ68IrTCRwA7kUrUeDsL47aYWAbUUrATqPOSOMQnOR4dJg-KcHq8WjwGAxORsVrAADucCJshJOT0eSYt3awHM-z0YwmP2mjkUUKhr3ee1p7glUJWkulHzhwARSIVy18xVhABkZABrBmYA5HNnYAASEQAsnqDcRDVdGDyAORNR2uxwWQq9QRiV0hV3zXgqNTADRiX28eqIE7kMRWGyMZysFjWVJ2AB0UQOoxDUNj0UGiYz11T6eT2Z+MFoBa8BaZUSOfQj8YAkgm4ABObtcLzi3xAA)

Comment: I have updated my question and playground, it needs to be a type argument because it is used in a conditional type.

Answer (score 1):

I made some change to your code [in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=54&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKKDGAeAonUGYAOwBMBnOXAG2AFsSYAaOAFQJCLMvJigEtiAcwB8cALxwA3gCg4cMFAhgA-AC44vAcIDccuEOAwiUcuun75AbQDWwRHEFsAuhoAUwWg2IwNuAJQSYlqCQjry+gC+MtEyoJCwcJjUAIbklKwAFqF4HFwUVF6MLOyEJAUhwmKy8pgQxFoArpgw0G6WCo0ARtT8mHDEKQwalUJMHYr8AG4pRJpY-ABmfbP89RoYwDi4JSLj8oFS0bHx0PBIKHAAkj7AUCkt0De8KcSYwLll3IX0xWx55R4fFCYkkWRyOzYIj0MgA9LC4ABxIwmK50MBFHyreqOHj8dG0KADCAAdwAdHA4uAzghkKhkcY7miMb8sTA1sRPpxAT9vMx-l8KsCqhILNYAAqOYgudwzaiNYAjYVCQLiMQ3EwPVpQZ4wV7vPC7PQnamJC6oDV3LXQVh0rn5Sg0Vn80rc76jUH6NxuOUKpXaFVBa63e6PHUNPVvD6Q1giQIAMn0DNRBOd2M5MehMmzp0Si0ab3ZOMwUGAs2A4OE9p5Tr5Ijcg2GmmVh30pZgjSg0vzhY52FdDubAfr5AWy0w6Y2WENUNb8lq9V4cFL5Ea1Hgkh7LQ5PpS8sVQ9C-g0laEM9jYvn8lo52ywlFxGAJLYd7PmYbQ2ALFHWyWKyLxD+HoV7yO2nbSjAr7AfOsRXmBXbLsAq7rnAaTBpqYa2ig55ZvIxzZvCbB0v8mR3Kg-CUIIixkaQqGUAA5F0iDguQ9EAD6McxmSzPRMh1BGcAADKCDYoolmWRCntgAASrAALKCcJxA2LWjD1vRvTKfR-huDUChKGAGj0Sk9H7AYKJ3OQGh6fITEse4njOqqYiOXyZKZKWixmbZXGzA5mIwM5BABWS7IwLQZmRGZJKZBAADCKQrgA6txMAsVcVlwAAbDlFKESxxLPkI0xIah0p3EoRJoaQSH8KWpAxEBBEIqw0kUbicAxQ4mz9I+wAFK0cBdKgKTmY+Aj9OaqFQEIjR8nCCJXHApAQJoEAMJopGDMQ-BCK8lHSoJEATtqzIBemCCrSkpC0ZBSGoIoyiUPUg13S+oQyEpNhknZqVuIxXTaeE+XZJQJLQKJaHxFsRC0cQpKfSJP1cRR-2YJgQNwCD7Xg1AkOUNDLT9YVC3oII7xCSJHUQIsRGXJaobalhHyyQpX2qT4LCcVkPEcb9FH0XsQ1cRA5CoCtpXw-AuM2IjynI1kovAP9N2Y9jlB7uQq0rmuMAHWVBBQJVMhAA) that I think solves your problem.

In your original code yuo had `S extends Spec<E>` as an type argument you passed around. This meant that Type `S` can allow extra properties.

However, by defining a Type argument `T extends string` which you pass around, your function argument is of type `Spec<E, T>` now instead of `S extends Spec<E>` which means it can't allow extra properties.

I include the modified code here as well:

```
export type Spec<E extends Element, T extends string> = {
  prop?: string;
  getters?: {
    [key in T]: (element: E) => string;  
  }
}

export class Thing<E extends Element, T extends string> {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    private specification: Spec<E, T>,
  ) {}
}

export type InteractorInstance<E extends Element, T extends string> = Thing<E, T>;

// GetterImplementation is simpler now. 
export type GetterImplementation<E extends Element, T extends string> = {
  [P in T]: (value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, T>;
}

export type InteractorType<E extends Element, T extends string> =
  ((value: string) => InteractorInstance<E, T>) &
  GetterImplementation<E, T>;


export function createThing<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return function<T extends string>(specification: Spec<E, T>) {
    const result = function(value: string): Thing<E, T> {
      let thing = new Thing<E, T>(name, specification);
      return thing;
    }

    return result as InteractorType<E, T>;
  }
}

// Type T here is infered as 'byThis'|'byThat'
const Link = createThing<HTMLLinkElement>('link')({
  prop: 'a',
  getters: {
    byThis: (element) => element.href,
    byThat: (element) => element.title,
  },
  whoCaresWhatThisIs: 666. // This now gives an error as desired
});

// THis is why Spec needs to be a generic type argument
// I do some shenanigans in LocatorImplementation to add these props onto the Thing
Link.byThat('bb'); // This work as expected now
Link.byThis('cc'); // This work as expected now
// Since Link is of Type InteractorType<HTMLLinkElement, 'byThat'|'byThis'>, byThose does not work
Link.byThose('dd'); // This also results in an error
```

I hope my answer solves your problem, and thank you for the question. Thinking about the solution helped learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, TS doesn't support excess property checks for generic parameter object literals. I think what you're looking for is exact types - something that's in discussion here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

What is possible is something a bit hacky on the basis that you can't assign a parameter which has a type never to a function. So here I check the generic to see if it meets the criteria, and then block if it isn't. The error message isn't the prettiest though.

```js
type EnforceKeyMatch<I extends {[KI in keyof T]: any }, T extends {[TI in keyof T]?: any }> = keyof I extends keyof T ? keyof T extends keyof I ? I : never : never;

export function createThing<E extends Element>(name: string) {
  return function<S extends Spec<E>>(specification: EnforceKeyMatch<S, Spec<Element>>) {
    const result = function(value: string): Thing<E, S> {
      let thing = new Thing<E, S>(name, specification);
      return thing;
    }

    return result as InteractorType<E, S>;
  }
}
```

With this I try to enforce that for the params to EnforceKeyMatch, the keys of I (input) extend the keys of T (target), and vice versa. This then spits out a never type if this condition is not met for specification.

So here with any extra property the type now errors:

[image]

But with the property removed it functions as normal:

[image]

[Here is a link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDKKDGAeAonUGYAOwBMBnOXAG2AFsSYA+OAXjgG8AoOOMKCGAD8ALjjkYUAJbEA5gG4ecWcBhEo5UXABKwTNFLYJ0uQBo4ACmC0GxGGNwBKNi2MzZTRQF8uXUJFg4TGoAQ3JKABUAC3c8AhAiMkoaekZzNHjEinQsPCYWbl59YmMAV0wYaAslXjBSgCNqKUw4YhCGMTczGr5pADcQonEsKQAzZsGpCGIxNFMlZw4fHz9waHgkFDgASTtgKBCK6F2JEOJMYDjCEmyU2xh0zJvKDD08lnZo2Nx0z19-dYIZCoADiqnU2zoYBsjEm0yuCWeVBhdke1ySOTeuHybE4SgA2gAFOAyOAAa2AiAgo3Q+IA5Co1PtyHSALqs2b0xnqFmsomsp4YixWFH2KjmAB0UpCUFk5DEpWIZOIEAA7sR8aznKwWIrlWriM4hJYBtRSsBOpJ3NqWLt1IdKlATjAzhc8L84GJiMA+vtvP81oFNqg7fsHdAIsCEVlkqK0YiMa8cNiPkphabzZaTLIbTs9gcjk6Si7zpcfugmM4AGRKMFMp1Q0Vw4juiuKXzBqjEUbQC4AaUpAFlBpgothtoLshx8X2J6SKVSaREOXAzog4F44OYIpPKNOInPiOTKdS4MutGuNx9j4udrub6ed8aF4-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)